# joining two tables in MySQL based on id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically I want to be able to join two tables to be able to get the id from a certain user to connect the booking to the user id.

tables exist like this "tbl_mem"

```
id      username       password    email  
 1       XXXXX            XXXX      XXXX
```

and "tbl_booking"

```
BookID    id    date   time  Confirmed
XXXX     XXX      XXX    XXX    XXXX
```

basically I want a table to have this

```
BookID   id   date   time   Confirmed
 1      XXXX    XXX    XXXX   XXXXX
```

I have an sql query at the moment like this

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tbl_mem.id, BookID, date, time, Confirmed
FROM tbl_mem
LEFT JOIN tbl_booking
ON tbl_mem.id=tbl_booking.id");
```

but honestly I have no idea what i'm doing with this part of the site, where would I place the sql query and is everything correct?

Comment: should use another key as foreign key in tbl_booking instead of (id), id should be its primary key.

Comment: Your tables are a bit strange, tbl_booking should have foreign key from tbl_mem.

Answer (score 0):

Your tbl_mem is ok, but tbl_booking should be like:

```
id   tbl_mem_id   date    confirmed
1    1            xxxx    xxxx
```

I used column date, because you can save both date and time in one column which is of type datetime. Also BookID is the id of the tbl_booking.

Now you can query it like this:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tbl_mem.id, tbl_booking.id as BookID, tbl_booking.date, tbl_booking.confirmed
FROM tbl_mem
LEFT JOIN tbl_booking
ON tbl_mem.id=tbl_booking.id
WHERE tbl_mem.id = 1");
```

EDIT: renamed tbl_booking.id to BookID for clarification in result set.

As for the part where would you place query, I guess somewhere before you want to display or process data.

Comment: Are you sure it is not working, I just tried this and it is working. What exactly are you trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

**Now you can query it like this:**

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT tb.BookID as BookID, tm.id as id, tb.date as date, tb.time as time, tb.Confirmed as Confirmed FROM tbl_mem as tm LEFT JOIN tbl_booking as tb ON tm.id = tb.id");
```